# What are the differences between the freemium and retail versions of Pokemon Rumble World?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

Pokemon Rumble World was originally released as a freemium game with micro transactions.  It has now been released as a retail game, that can be purchased in shops.

Presumably in the retail version they have removed the ongoing costs of play, but how has this been achieved?

- Do you receive an infinite supply of in-game currency, and the same cool downs are applied?
- Have those aspects been removed entirely?
- Has another approach again been used?

Beyond the removal of in game purchases, have any other changes been made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you receive an infinite supply of in-game currency?

> In the package version, you'll obtain 3,000 Poké Diamonds and a *Poké Diamond Digger* at the in-game shop after the tutorial ends. The *Poké Diamond Digger* will give you 40 Poké Diamonds every day.

Are cool downs applied? Have those aspects been removed entirely?

> Additionally, you'll be able to pick up Pokémon VIP Cards in the in-game shop. The Balloon VIP card lets you inflate any hot-air balloon for just 1 Poké Diamond. The Timing Stop VIP Card lets you use the Timing Stop to pick which stage you'd like to visit for only one Poké Diamond, too. (You'll need to get the Timing Stop before acquiring the Timing Stop VIP Card).

And, as you wrote, there are no in-game purchases in the package version of Pokémon Rumble World.

Source [PokemonRumble](http://www.pokemonrumble.com/world/en-gb/explore/).